# Using IBM Connections 5.5 - Unable to display Widgets in Community Detail Page and My Page

Tags: websphere, ibm-connections

We are using IBM Connections 5.5. SSO has been done with IBM TAM environment. 
Until some time back the application was working fine. However, now after creating a community, system is unable to load Widget details. Only the heading is shown with an option to Move Up / Down etc.

Bookmarks work fine as expected. No other widget like Status Updates, Forums, Members are shown

'My Page' is also unable to load any of the widget.

Upon doing <kbd>F12</kbd> and viewing browser console it says:

```
Unable to Load data and Malformed json returned by processWidget call.
```

System.out log says:

```
Failed to generate process widget json. Unexpected character < on line1, column 1
```